# Issue in fedex maximum supported weight is 150 by default

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex

i know maximum supported weight is 150 pound by default in magento.

1. when i am adding same product (weight 50 pound) four times (Now weight 200 pound). **Fedex ground should not have appear in frontend** (in checkout page)  but **fedex ground method is appearing** though weight is 200pound now. 
   What happen to "maximum supported weight" in this case ?
2. When i am adding product (weight 151 pound), **fedex method is not appearing.** It is working well in this case as maximum supported weight is 150 pound.
3. It is also working well if i add product (weight 149 pound), **in this case Fedex is appearing.**

------------**************--------------

I only want to know what happen to maximum supported weight in case 1.

If anyone know the exact reason, please sort out my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the maximum supported weight is for a single package. If you have multiple quantity of 50 pound product, they can be shipped in separate packages but a single product cannot ship in multiple packages.

Comment: maximum supported weight is 150 pound for 1 box not for entire shipment.shipment is divided in multiple boxes based on QTY of products in quote or order.

Comment: if package is more than 1 then they would be shipped as different packages and max is 150lbs

Comment: May i know how you feed your weight?  eg: 20 (kg) or 44.09(pound)

Comment: in pound (50 pound)